# Trying to optimize linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to create a `linq` query to do the following:

1. Get count of all users
2. Get count of all official users
3. Get count of all non-official users

So far I have come up with the below:

```
var query = context.Users;

List<Users> users = query.ToList();
int totalUsers = users.Count;
int officialUsers = users.Where(s => s.IsOfficialUser).ToList().Count;
int nonOfficialUsers = users.Where(s => !s.IsOfficialUser).ToList().Count;
```

I'm not sure how much performance impact will happen by me calling `.ToList()` numerous times. So I was hoping is there a way to optimize the query or am I on the right track?

Comment: You could combine both `Where()` in one for-loop and count official and non-official users at the same time. Besides, in your current code, the call to `ToList()` is not necessary as you could call `Count()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy optimisation:

```
int totalUsers = users.Count;
int officialUsers = users.Where(s => s.IsOfficialUser).ToList().Count;
int nonOfficialUsers = totalUsers - officialUsers;
```

Once this line of code is run `List<Users> users = query.ToList();` the query is immediately executed.

You don't need the `ToList()` again after that, see here:

```
int totalUsers = users.Count;
int officialUsers = users.Count(s => s.IsOfficialUser);
int nonOfficialUsers = totalUsers - officialUsers;
```

Comment: Why not just  Count(s => s.IsOfficialUser)

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I was just getting to that, someone interupted me pinching my answers...

Comment: Thank you for this! you made it look so simple. Just a quick further question if you don't mind please. I have `bool` property in the `User` entity named `ShowUser` and based on a `bool` parameter being passed in the method I have an `if` & `else` clause where I am duplicating the code as I posted in my question. Where would it be ideal to include that in the `where` clause? If this is out of scope then I can ask another question. I appreciate your help

Comment: Will something like this `.Where(u => showAll ? u.ShowUser : !u.ShowUser);` work?

Comment: Perhaps `List<Users> users = query.Where(s => s.ShowUser == boolParameter).ToList();`

Answer (score 3):

Using `.ToList` on a materialized list will only impact the amount of memory required. While this can technically have a performance hit, it is unlikely unless you have millions of users; in which case, you would honestly probably have the server RAM available anyway.

The `.ToList` certainly isn't required though. All you are needing to do is count the differentiation here, so you can skip the ToList, and the Where (as Count accepts a Func)

```
int officialUsers = users.Count(s => s.IsOfficialUser);
int nonOfficialUsers = users.Count(s => !s.IsOfficialUser);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even know `Count` accepts a `Func`

Answer (score 0):

What about this method?

- Group your collection based on `IsOfficialUser` which gives you two collections of `nonOfficialUsers` and `officialUsers` right?
- Get the count of those collections separately to get the respective counts
- Sum of these counts will be the total right?

Now try [this Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUcAOo):

```
 var groupedUsers = users.GroupBy(x => x.IsOfficialUser).ToDictionary(g =>  g.Key, g=>g.Count());
 int officialUsers = groupedUsers[true];
 int nonOfficialUsers = groupedUsers[false];
 int totalUsers = nonOfficialUsers + officialUsers;
```